# Create the [cofoundry] tag

Tags: support, tags, tag-creation-request

Can someone create a tag for [Cofoundry](https://www.cofoundry.org) for me please?

#### Explain how the tag helps in categorising and finding those questions

Cofoundry is a .NET Core CMS and questions would typically be specific to Cofoundry rather than the broader .NET framework.

I work on Cofoundry and would like to help people who ask questions about it on here, but users are currently unable to tag their questions with cofoundry and I'm unable to subscribe to notifications for it.

We do have [issues on GitHub](https://github.com/cofoundry-cms/cofoundry/issues) and gitter for chat, but some users find Stack Overflow a better place to ask questions.

#### Existing questions where the tag would be appropriate

- [cofoundry 0.40 hangfire admin section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353187/cofoundry-0-40-hangfire-admin-section)
- [Get data from cofoundry database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53016015/get-data-from-cofoundry-database/53154286#53154286)
- [Using different database with cofoundry CMS for .net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52004178/using-different-database-with-cofoundry-cms-for-net-core)

#### Tag name:

[cofoundry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cofoundry)

#### Excerpt:

Cofoundry is an open source CMS for .NET Core. Use this tag for any questions relating to implementing the CMS or framework in your application. Any bugs or feature requests should be reported through the Cofoundry GitHub issue tracker.

#### Wiki

Cofoundry is an open source CMS for .NET Core focusing on code first development and unobtrusive integration into your application.

Use this tag for any questions relating to implementing the CMS or framework in your application. Any bugs or feature requests should be reported through the Cofoundry [GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/cofoundry-cms/cofoundry/issues).

Find out more about Cofoundry at [www.cofoundry.org](https://www.cofoundry.org)

Comment: Given the average quality of tag requests, this is way above average and I don't see anything that speaks against it. I'm not sure why it got three downvotes in 10 minutes. Could anyone provide some feedback why they think the tag shouldn't be created?

Comment: Does anyone know why the tag info didn't get added? OP even included actual usage guidance in their question.

Comment: @BSMP there are pending suggested edits which need to be reviewed

Comment: @BDL If I had to guess, they're high-rep users who didn't realize that low-rep users can't create tags, and are therefore complaining that someone's asking on meta instead of just doing it themselves. I didn't downvote, though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Someone has now created the tag : [cofoundry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cofoundry).

Enjoy!

Comment: Likely, [tbodt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1455016/tbodt) or [GrumpyCrouton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5827005/grumpycrouton) did.

Comment: @Cœur, I am curious, [where do you](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53159038/revisions) see tbodt?

Comment: @Sinatr tbodt added the tag here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52353187/timeline#history_10df00bc-7170-47e0-b26a-66905b958ab8. GrumpyCrouton only added a description twenty minutes later.

Comment: @Cœur, ah timeline of questions , thanks.